# Oracle doesn't use index with dynamic time_interval value resulting in higher cost

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a performance issue related to an Oracle query where the cost varies significantly depending on how I set the time_interval value.

When I hard-code the time_interval value (e.g., WHERE o.request_time > SYSDATE - 15/1440), the execution plan shows that it uses an index, and the cost is low.

However, when I use a dynamic value from a joined table (e.g., WHERE o.request_time > SYSDATE - c.time_interval/1440), the execution plan doesn't use the index, and the cost becomes significantly higher.

Here's a simplified version of my query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table_1 o
    ,table_2 c 
WHERE o.request_time > SYSDATE - c.time_interval/1440;
```

in table_1 request_time is indexed.

I was expecting the execution plan to consistently use the index regardless of whether the time_interval was static or fetched dynamically from the joined table. My main goal is to understand why the dynamic time_interval prevents the optimizer from using the index and to optimize the query to ensure a consistently low cost.

this is actual query:

```
SELECT c.state
      ,c.critical_msg_quotes
      ,COUNT(1) AS critical_msg_count
FROM  operations    o
     ,configuration c
WHERE o.state = c.state
  AND o.request_time > sysdate - c.time_interval / 1440
GROUP BY c.state
        ,c.critical_msg_quotes
```

Comment: In the query you posted, if you changed the predicate to hard-code the value, you'd be doing a Cartesian join between the two tables.  So my guess is you mean that if you do a single-table query against table_1 the index is used but it is not used when you try to join the two tables?  Either way, it's super helpful to include the actual SQL you're running in both cases and the actual plans.

Comment: Conceptually, before the query is executed, the parser/optimiser doesn't know what value `c.time_interval` has, so it doesn't know if the filter is likely to match 0%, 1%, 10%, 50% or 100% of the rows in `o`. So it can't assume using the index would be more efficient. Of course it's more complicated than that and it has lots of tricks to try to help, and without the real queries and plans we can only guess what might be happening.

Comment: i already added actual query. @AlexPoole

Comment: You should post your index definition *and* the Oracle version

Answer (score 1):

When you use a literal like `SYSDATE - 15/1440`, Oracle can consult the column `high_value`, `low_value`, `num_distinct` and histograms collected by stats gathering (`DBA_TAB_COL_STATISTICS`) to calculate an estimate of what percentage of your rows are likely to have dates in this narrow range. Using this information, it is able to thus determine that you want a very small number of rows relative to your entire table, and that makes using an index a more appealing choice.

However, when you use a value from somewhere else, Oracle cannot predict what the value will be since it depends on the results of a join between two tables. In this case, the optimizer makes looser assumptions about the cardinalities and very frequently its calculations are significantly off (by orders of magnitude). If it believes your predicate will match a significant portion of the table, it will bypass the index and do a full table scan, which *would* be the best method if it's assumption were correct. A full scan is better than using an index when you want more than a very small slice of a table. Oracle is just trying to choose what's best based on what it knows, which is limited.

You know something it doesn't: that the result of that join will give `time_interval` values that will drive a very small window of time. To fix this, you should have a two-column index on `(state,request_time)` in that order and add a hint to your query:

```
CREATE INDEX operations_1ix ON operations (state,request_time) COMPRESS 1;

SELECT /*+ LEADING(c) USE_NL_WITH_INDEX(o) */
       c.state
      ,c.critical_msg_quotes
      ,COUNT(1) AS critical_msg_count
FROM  operations    o
     ,configuration c
WHERE o.state = c.state
  AND o.request_time > sysdate - c.time_interval / 1440
GROUP BY c.state
        ,c.critical_msg_quotes
```

Lastly, please ignore `COST`, it plays no role whatsoever in performance tuning. If Oracle's making a mistake, by definition it's calculation of `COST` is incorrect, so the value should mean nothing. Oracle will *always* choose the plan with the lowest `COST` value. But that's a hard number to get right.

Answer (score 0):

The index on `request_time` only is inappropriate for your query, you need an index on `state,request_time`

If you have a recent version of Oracle (>= 12) you should see  an *an [adaptive plan](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/query-optimizer-concepts.html#GUID-5A1EB094-1A9E-4B69-9BE5-39BDA2B3253C)* that could switch between hash join with a full access to nested loops with index range scan on the operations table – see example below

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   Id  | Operation                | Name           | Starts |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |                |      1 |  
|     1 |  HASH GROUP BY           |                |      1 |   
|  *  2 |   HASH JOIN              |                |      1 |     
|-    3 |    NESTED LOOPS          |                |      1 |     
|-    4 |     STATISTICS COLLECTOR |                |      1 |     
|     5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL   | CONFIGURATION  |      1 |    
|- *  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN     | OPERATIONS_IDX |      0 |  
|     7 |    INDEX FULL SCAN       | OPERATIONS_IDX |      1 |    
--------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("O"."STATE"="C"."STATE")
       filter("O"."REQUEST_TIME">SYSDATE@!-"C"."TIME_INTERVAL"/1440)
   6 - access("O"."STATE"="C"."STATE" AND "O"."REQUEST_TIME">SYSDATE@!-"C"."TIME_INTERVAL"/1440 AND "O"."REQUEST_TIME" IS NOT NULL)
 
Note
-----
   - this is an adaptive plan (rows marked '-' are inactive)
```

If you have still a performance problem with your query  the next option is to *range partition* the operations table (ask a new question if so).